# Can't run the job after store in database

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, hsqldb

I use the latest version of Quartz-2.2.1 and HSQL-2.3.2. And i have a problem with performing job after saving it in db.  The same code using mySql connections works - the job is launched automatically after store. Using HSQL it doesnt act at all, only store in db.

MyJOB.class

```
public MyJob() {
    this.myJob = newJob(SimpleQuartzJob.class).withIdentity("myJob",
    "group").build();
}
```

MyTrigger.class

```
private Trigger trigger;
public MyTrigger() {
    trigger = newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("myTrigger", "group")
            .startNow()
            .withSchedule(
                    simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(1)
                            .repeatForever()).build();
}
```

SimpleQuatzJob.class

```
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
        throws JobExecutionException {
    try {
        System.out.println("=)");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

main()

```
SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
final Scheduler sd = sf.getScheduler();
sd.start();
MyJob job = new MyJob();
MyTrigger trigger = new MyTrigger();
sd.scheduleJob(job.getMyJob(), trigger.getMyTrigger());
```

properties:

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = test_scheduler

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool

org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 4

org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX

org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false

org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = qrtz_

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000

org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = false

org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.HSQLDBDelegate

org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS

org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver = org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver

org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL = jdbc:hsqldb:file:D:\files\mydatabase\testdb

org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user = sa

org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password =

org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.shutdown=true

org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections = 50

---

And the same with server mode:

```
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL = jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001/
```

---

Could someone give me an advise what's wrong with this code because I cannot get it to work for several days already. Thanks in advance.